# "Research and development of something" or "Research and development on something"

Tags: prepositions

"we perform research on technology", and "we perform development of technology". But when we perform "research and development", should "of" or "on" be used?

Comment: _We perform technological research and development._

Comment: If two terms joined by ***and*** would normally take different prepositions, the idiomatic standard in English is that *we use the preposition that suits the **second** term*. So in your case it should be *research and development **of** [whatever]* - or for different pairings, *funding and research **into** [some project]* and *research and funding **for** [the project]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image][image: trial]

[These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=research+and+development+of%2Cresearch+and+development+in%2Cresearch+and+development+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresearch%20and%20development%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresearch%20and%20development%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresearch%20and%20development%20on%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cresearch%20and%20development%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresearch%20and%20development%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresearch%20and%20development%20on%3B%2Cc0) show that both 'on' and 'of', and additionally 'in', are used; 'on' lags behind the others, probably because 'development on ...' sounds incongruous.

False positives abound, especially with locative 'in', but the domain usage also exists:

> Learn about working at National Institute for Research and Development
>   in Informatics (ICI).  [[LinkedIn_ICI](https://www.linkedin.com/company/national-institute-for-research-and-development-in-informatics-ici-)]

......................................................

With 'of', there seems to have been a dropping of the normal rule that relevant prepositions always need to be inserted (one would expect say research on/in and development of); this is a typical example:

> Research and development of medical products: opportunities and
>   challenges [[The Academy of Medical Sciences](https://acmedsci.ac.uk/policy/policy-projects/research-and-development-of-medical-products)]

......................................................

Likewise with 'on', with not even a proximity argument:

> The research and development on a single compound pharmaceutical from
>   a herbal medicine requires inputs of hundreds of millions of dollars
>   and typically ... [[ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/social-sciences/research-and-development)]

.....

> This debate pack is prepared for a general debate on research and
>   development on tackling infectious diseases. [[UK Parliament Research
>   Briefings](https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/ResearchBriefing/Summary/CDP-2017-0118)]

.....

> Institute of Research and Development on Photovoltaic Energy [[Nature
>   Index_IRDEP](https://www.natureindex.com/institution-outputs/france/institute-of-research-and-development-on-photovoltaic-energy-irdep/52660aa7140ba0fd7b00000e)]

......................................................

While the 'of' variant lends itself more naturally to things that are developed and the 'in' variant to conceptual fields or other domains (eg industries), the last three examples show that the prepositional complement of 'on' is not narrowly scoped; products (things made), or more or less abstract concerns / concepts are referents with complements filling this slot.

Answer (score 0):

R&D *of* would apply to something already defined - 'research and development of electric cars' for example.

R&D *on* is more suitable to abstract concepts - 'she is engaged in research and development on the *potential* of electric cars'.